# Riemann integral proof $\int^b_a f(x) \, dx>0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Prove that if $f$ is a continuous real valued function on the interval $[a,b]$ such that $f(x)\ge 0$  for all $x\in [a,b]$ and $f(x)>0$ for some $x\in[a,b]$ then $\int^b_a f(x) \, dx >0$.

The definition I have for Riemann integral is: Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ $a<b$ and let $f$ be a real valued function on $[a,b]$. We say that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ if there exists a number $A\in \mathbb{R}$ such that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|S-A|<\varepsilon$ whenever $S$ is Riemann sum for $f$ corresponding to any partition of $[a,b]$ of width less that $\delta$.

Comment: If you show that there's ONE partition for which the lower Riemann sum is positive, then the rest is routine facts about Riemann integrals.  You need continuity of $f$ to show that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int\limits_a^bf(x) \, dx \geq 0$ as the minimum value of $f(x) \geq 0$ on that interval. Now since the function is continuous and $f(x)>0$ for some $x$ we actually have an interval $[c,d] \subseteq [a,b]$ where $f(x) >0$. Since $f$ is continuous, it achieves its minimum value on this interval, say $m$. Now, $m >0$ as $f(x)>0$ on this interval.

So, $\int_c^d f(x) \, dx >\int_c^d m \, dx= m(d-c)>0$.

Comment: Voldemort, do you think you can add more detail to your proof?

Comment: @user104235: Sure. Let me know what statement in the above proof you do not fully understand, and I shall add the proofs of those statements.

Comment: I don't know how you got this statement, "Then $\int\limits_c^df(x) \, dx > 0$ (again integral is $\geq$ the minimum)". Can you prove that for me?

Comment: @user104235: I have added the proof- do let me know if you need further clarifications.